# Solving sparse definite positive linear systems in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, linear-algebra, solver, cusolver

We are experiencing problems while using `cuSOLVER`'s `cusolverSpScsrlsvchol` function, probably due to misunderstanding of the `cuSOLVER` library.

Motivation: we are solving the Poisson equation `-divgrad x = b` on a rectangular grid. In `2` dimensions with a `5`-stencil `(1, 1, -4, 1, 1)`, the Laplacian on the grid provides a (quite sparse) matrix `A`. Moreover, the charge distribution on the grid gives a (dense) vector `b`. `A` is positive definite and symmetric.

Now we solve `A * x = b` for `x` using nvidia's new `cuSOLVER` library that comes with CUDA 7.0 . It provides a function `cusolverSpScsrlsvchol` which should do the sparse Cholesky factorisation for floats.

Note: we are able to correctly solve the system with the alternative sparse QR factorisation function `cusolverSpScsrlsvqr`. For a `4 x 4` grid with all `b` entries on the edge being `1` and the rest `0`, we get for `x`:

```
1 1 0.999999 1 1 1 0.999999 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Our problems:

1. `cusolverSpScsrlsvchol` returns wrong results for `x`:

   ```
   1 3.33333 2.33333 1 3.33333 2.33333 1.33333 1 2.33333 1.33333 0.666667 1 1 1 1 1
   ```
2. (solved, see answer below) Converting the CSR matrix `A` to a dense matrix and showing the output gives weird numbers (`10^-44` and the like). The respective data from the CSR format are correct and validated with python numpy.
3. (solved, see answer below) The alternative sparse `LU` and partial pivoting with `cusolverSpScsrlsvlu` cannot even be found:

   ```
   $ nvcc -std=c++11 cusparse_test3.cu -o cusparse_test3 -lcusparse -lcusolver
   cusparse_test3.cu(208): error: identifier "cusolverSpScsrlsvlu" is undefined
   ```

What are we doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Our C++ CUDA code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cusolverSp.h>
#include <cusparse.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>


// create poisson matrix with Dirichlet bc. of a rectangular grid with
// dimension NxN
void assemble_poisson_matrix_coo(std::vector<float>& vals, std::vector<int>& row, std::vector<int>& col,
                     std::vector<float>& rhs, int Nrows, int Ncols) {

        //nnz: 5 entries per row (node) for nodes in the interior
    // 1 entry per row (node) for nodes on the boundary, since we set them explicitly to 1.
    int nnz = 5*Nrows*Ncols - (2*(Ncols-1) + 2*(Nrows-1))*4;
    vals.resize(nnz);
    row.resize(nnz);
    col.resize(nnz);
    rhs.resize(Nrows*Ncols);

    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Ncols; ++j) {
            int idx = j + Ncols*i;
            if (i == 0 || j == 0 || j == Ncols-1 || i == Nrows-1) {
                vals[counter] = 1.;
                row[counter] = idx;
                col[counter] = idx;
                counter++;
                rhs[idx] = 1.;
//                if (i == 0) {
//                    rhs[idx] = 3.;
//                }
            } else { // -laplace stencil
                // above
                vals[counter] = -1.;
                row[counter] = idx;
                col[counter] = idx-Ncols;
                counter++;
                // left
                vals[counter] = -1.;
                row[counter] = idx;
                col[counter] = idx-1;
                counter++;
                // center
                vals[counter] = 4.;
                row[counter] = idx;
                col[counter] = idx;
                counter++;
                // right
                vals[counter] = -1.;
                row[counter] = idx;
                col[counter] = idx+1;
                counter++;
                // below
                vals[counter] = -1.;
                row[counter] = idx;
                col[counter] = idx+Ncols;
                counter++;

                rhs[idx] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    assert(counter == nnz);
}



int main() {
    // --- create library handles:
    cusolverSpHandle_t cusolver_handle;
    cusolverStatus_t cusolver_status;
    cusolver_status = cusolverSpCreate(&cusolver_handle);
    std::cout << "status create cusolver handle: " << cusolver_status << std::endl;

    cusparseHandle_t cusparse_handle;
    cusparseStatus_t cusparse_status;
    cusparse_status = cusparseCreate(&cusparse_handle);
    std::cout << "status create cusparse handle: " << cusparse_status << std::endl;

    // --- prepare matrix:
    int Nrows = 4;
    int Ncols = 4;
    std::vector<float> csrVal;
    std::vector<int> cooRow;
    std::vector<int> csrColInd;
    std::vector<float> b;

    assemble_poisson_matrix_coo(csrVal, cooRow, csrColInd, b, Nrows, Ncols);

    int nnz = csrVal.size();
    int m = Nrows * Ncols;
    std::vector<int> csrRowPtr(m+1);

    // --- prepare solving and copy to GPU:
    std::vector<float> x(m);
    float tol = 1e-5;
    int reorder = 0;
    int singularity = 0;

    float *db, *dcsrVal, *dx;
    int *dcsrColInd, *dcsrRowPtr, *dcooRow;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&db, m*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dx, m*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dcsrVal, nnz*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dcsrColInd, nnz*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dcsrRowPtr, (m+1)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dcooRow, nnz*sizeof(int));

    cudaMemcpy(db, b.data(), b.size()*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dcsrVal, csrVal.data(), csrVal.size()*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dcsrColInd, csrColInd.data(), csrColInd.size()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dcooRow, cooRow.data(), cooRow.size()*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    cusparse_status = cusparseXcoo2csr(cusparse_handle, dcooRow, nnz, m,
                                       dcsrRowPtr, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);
    std::cout << "status cusparse coo2csr conversion: " << cusparse_status << std::endl;

    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // matrix format conversion has to be finished!

    // --- everything ready for computation:

    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;

    cusparse_status = cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA);
    std::cout << "status cusparse createMatDescr: " << cusparse_status << std::endl;

    // optional: print dense matrix that has been allocated on GPU

    std::vector<float> A(m*m, 0);
    float *dA;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dA, A.size()*sizeof(float));

    cusparseScsr2dense(cusparse_handle, m, m, descrA, dcsrVal,
                       dcsrRowPtr, dcsrColInd, dA, m);

    cudaMemcpy(A.data(), dA, A.size()*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << "A: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            std::cout << A[i*m + j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    cudaFree(dA);

    std::cout << "b: \n";
    cudaMemcpy(b.data(), db, (m)*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for (auto a : b) {
        std::cout << a << ",";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    // --- solving!!!!

//    cusolver_status = cusolverSpScsrlsvchol(cusolver_handle, m, nnz, descrA, dcsrVal,
//                       dcsrRowPtr, dcsrColInd, db, tol, reorder, dx,
//                       &singularity);

     cusolver_status = cusolverSpScsrlsvqr(cusolver_handle, m, nnz, descrA, dcsrVal,
                        dcsrRowPtr, dcsrColInd, db, tol, reorder, dx,
                        &singularity);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    std::cout << "singularity (should be -1): " << singularity << std::endl;

    std::cout << "status cusolver solving (!): " << cusolver_status << std::endl;

    cudaMemcpy(x.data(), dx, m*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // relocated these 2 lines from above to solve (2):
    cusparse_status = cusparseDestroy(cusparse_handle);
    std::cout << "status destroy cusparse handle: " << cusparse_status << std::endl;

    cusolver_status = cusolverSpDestroy(cusolver_handle);
    std::cout << "status destroy cusolver handle: " << cusolver_status << std::endl;

    for (auto a : x) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;



    cudaFree(db);
    cudaFree(dx);
    cudaFree(dcsrVal);
    cudaFree(dcsrColInd);
    cudaFree(dcsrRowPtr);
    cudaFree(dcooRow);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts or comments are appreciated, we also brought our issue up in the nvidia devtalk forums: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/836451/cuda-programming-and-performance/cusolver-into-python-possibly-for-pycuda-/?offset=2#4544646

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1.cusolverSpScsrlsvchol returns wrong results for x:
>   1 3.33333 2.33333 1 3.33333 2.33333 1.33333 1 2.33333 1.33333 0.666667 1 1 1 1 1

You said:

> A is positive definite and symmetric.

No, it is not.  It is not symmetric.

[cusolverSpcsrlsvqr()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cusolver-lt-t-gt-csrlsvqr) has no requirement that the `A` matrix be symmetric.

[cusolverSpcsrlsvchol()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cusolver-lt-t-gt-csrlsvchol) does have that requirement:

> A is an m×m symmetric postive definite sparse matrix

This is the printout your code provides for the A matrix:

```
A:
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  1  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  1  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  4 -1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0 -1  4  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  4 -1  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  4  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  1  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

If that were symmetric, I would expect the second row:

```
0 1 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

to match the 2nd column:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

By the way, a suggestion about Stack Overflow.  If you answer your own question, my suggestion is that you intend it to be a *complete* answer.  Some people might see an answered question and skip it.  Probably better to edit such content into your question, thus focusing your question (I think) down to a single question.  SO also doesn't work as well in my opinion when you ask multiple questions per question.  That sort of behavior makes the question unnecessarily more difficult to answer, and I don't think it is serving you well here.

Comment: Yes, indeed you're right and the matrix is asymmetric, thank you for pointing out our blatant error... (you printed the transposed matrix though, as the dense format is column-major)

Comment: by introducing Dirichlet boundaries within the matrix, we make it asymmetric. For the inner nodes the Laplace matrix is symmetric... 

For interested readers, there are mechanisms to hide the asymmetry introduced by the Dirichlet boundary condition and let it only run over the inner nodes in `A`.

Answer (score 4):

Although the matrix arising from Cartesian discretization of the Poisson equation is not positive definite, this question regards the inversion of **sparse positive definite linear systems**.

In the meanwhile `cusolverSpScsrlsvchol` becomes available for the device channel, I think it will be useful for potentially interested users to perform inversions of **sparse positive definite linear systems** using the cuSPARSE library. Here is a fully worked example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse_v2.h>

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
// --- Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) { exit(code); }
   }
}

extern "C" void gpuErrchk(cudaError_t ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/***************************/
/* CUSPARSE ERROR CHECKING */
/***************************/
static const char *_cusparseGetErrorEnum(cusparseStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if(CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSPARSE error in file '%s', line %Ndims\Nobjs %s\nerror %Ndims: %s\nterminating!\Nobjs",__FILE__, __LINE__,err, \
                                _cusparseGetErrorEnum(err)); \
        cudaDeviceReset(); assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err) { __cusparseSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseHandle_t handle;    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    const int Nrows = 4;                        // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 4;                        // --- Number of columns
    const int N     = Nrows;

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A_dense = (double*)malloc(Nrows*Ncols*sizeof(*h_A_dense));

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_A_dense[0] = 0.4612f;  h_A_dense[4] = -0.0006f;   h_A_dense[8]  = 0.3566f; h_A_dense[12] = 0.0f; 
    h_A_dense[1] = -0.0006f; h_A_dense[5] = 0.4640f;    h_A_dense[9]  = 0.0723f; h_A_dense[13] = 0.0f; 
    h_A_dense[2] = 0.3566f;  h_A_dense[6] = 0.0723f;    h_A_dense[10] = 0.7543f; h_A_dense[14] = 0.0f; 
    h_A_dense[3] = 0.f;      h_A_dense[7] = 0.0f;       h_A_dense[11] = 0.0f;    h_A_dense[15] = 0.1f; 

    // --- Create device array and copy host array to it
    double *d_A_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense, h_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix A
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;      cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE));  

    int nnz = 0;                                // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix
    const int lda = Nrows;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix
    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *d_nnzPerVector;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*d_nnzPerVector)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, &nnz));
    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *h_nnzPerVector = (int *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVector, d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix = %i\n\n", nnz);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVector[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // --- Device side dense matrix
    double *d_A;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, nnz * sizeof(*d_A)));
    int *d_A_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*d_A_RowIndices)));
    int *d_A_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*d_A_ColIndices)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices));

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A));     
    int *h_A_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices));
    int *h_A_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, nnz*sizeof(*h_A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_RowIndices, d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_ColIndices, d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("\nOriginal matrix in CSR format\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("A[%i] = %.0f ", i, h_A[i]); printf("\n");

    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < (Nrows + 1); ++i) printf("h_A_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("h_A_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_ColIndices[i]);   

    // --- Allocating and defining dense host and device data vectors
    double *h_x = (double *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(double)); 
    h_x[0] = 100.0;  h_x[1] = 200.0; h_x[2] = 400.0; h_x[3] = 500.0;

    double *d_x;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_x, Nrows * sizeof(double)));   
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_x, h_x, Nrows * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    /******************************************/
    /* STEP 1: CREATE DESCRIPTORS FOR L AND U */
    /******************************************/
    cusparseMatDescr_t      descr_L = 0; 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr (&descr_L)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatIndexBase    (descr_L, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatType     (descr_L, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatFillMode (descr_L, CUSPARSE_FILL_MODE_LOWER)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseSetMatDiagType (descr_L, CUSPARSE_DIAG_TYPE_NON_UNIT)); 

    /********************************************************************************************************/
    /* STEP 2: QUERY HOW MUCH MEMORY USED IN CHOLESKY FACTORIZATION AND THE TWO FOLLOWING SYSTEM INVERSIONS */
    /********************************************************************************************************/
    csric02Info_t info_A  = 0;  cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsric02Info(&info_A)); 
    csrsv2Info_t  info_L  = 0;  cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrsv2Info (&info_L)); 
    csrsv2Info_t  info_Lt = 0;  cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateCsrsv2Info (&info_Lt)); 

    int pBufferSize_M, pBufferSize_L, pBufferSize_Lt;
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsric02_bufferSize(handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_A, &pBufferSize_M)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_bufferSize (handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnz, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_L,  &pBufferSize_L)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_bufferSize (handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE,     N, nnz, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_Lt, &pBufferSize_Lt)); 

    int pBufferSize = max(pBufferSize_M, max(pBufferSize_L, pBufferSize_Lt)); 
    void *pBuffer = 0;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&pBuffer, pBufferSize)); 

    /******************************************************************************************************/
    /* STEP 3: ANALYZE THE THREE PROBLEMS: CHOLESKY FACTORIZATION AND THE TWO FOLLOWING SYSTEM INVERSIONS */
    /******************************************************************************************************/
    int structural_zero; 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsric02_analysis(handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_A, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 

    cusparseStatus_t status = cusparseXcsric02_zeroPivot(handle, info_A, &structural_zero); 
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT == status){ printf("A(%d,%d) is missing\n", structural_zero, structural_zero); } 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnz, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_L,  CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL,  pBuffer)); 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_analysis(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE,     N, nnz, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_Lt, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_USE_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 

    /*************************************/
    /* STEP 4: FACTORIZATION: A = L * L' */
    /*************************************/
    int numerical_zero; 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsric02(handle, N, nnz, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_A, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 
    status = cusparseXcsric02_zeroPivot(handle, info_A, &numerical_zero); 
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT == status){ printf("L(%d,%d) is zero\n", numerical_zero, numerical_zero); } 

    printf("\nNon-zero elements in Cholesky matrix\n\n");
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, nnz * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int k=0; k<nnz; k++) printf("%f\n", h_A[k]);

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsr2dense(handle, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, d_A_dense, Nrows));

    printf("\nCholesky matrix\n\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++)
            std::cout << h_A_dense[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    /*********************/
    /* STEP 5: L * z = x */
    /*********************/
    // --- Allocating the intermediate result vector
    double *d_z;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_z, N * sizeof(double))); 

    const double alpha = 1.; 
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_solve(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, N, nnz, &alpha, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_L, d_x, d_z, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_NO_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 

    /**********************/
    /* STEP 5: L' * y = z */
    /**********************/
    // --- Allocating the host and device side result vector
    double *h_y = (double *)malloc(Ncols * sizeof(double)); 
    double *d_y;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_y, Ncols * sizeof(double))); 

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDcsrsv2_solve(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_TRANSPOSE, N, nnz, &alpha, descr_L, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices, info_Lt, d_z, d_y, CUSPARSE_SOLVE_POLICY_USE_LEVEL, pBuffer)); 

    cudaMemcpy(h_x, d_y, N * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("\n\nFinal result\n");
    for (int k=0; k<N; k++) printf("x[%i] = %f\n", k, h_x[k]);
}
```

Comment: I really liked your error checking functions. I've adapted a bit changing `char *` to `std::string`s so my compiler stops showing warnings. But I couldn't use `gpuErrchk` like you did. I had to use `#define`, as in the link you gave, because `__LINE__` would always show my `gpuErrchk` definition line. Should `extern "C"` solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning 2: we have destroyed the cusparse handle too early (probably too much micro-tweaking to find the error sources....). Besides, the dense format is column-major which is why we need to transpose `A` to make it print properly!

Concerning 3: `cusolverSpScsrlsvlu` only exists on the host for the moment -- it's written in the documentation in a wonderfully obvious way under 6.2.1 remark 5.... http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cusolver-lt-t-gt-csrlsvlu

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to solve a sparse, positive definite linear system is using the `cuSOLVER` library and, in particular, the `cusolverSpDcsrlsvchol` routine. It works very similar to the `cuSOLVER` routines used to [Solving general sparse linear systems in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840341/solving-general-sparse-linear-systems-in-cuda), but uses a Cholesky factorization `A = G * G^H`, where `G` is the Cholesky factor, a lower triangular matrix.

As for the routines in [Solving general sparse linear systems in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840341/solving-general-sparse-linear-systems-in-cuda) and as of `CUDA 10.0`, only the host channel is at the moment available. Note that the `reorder` parameter has no effect and `singularity` is `-1` if the matrix `A` is positive definite.

Below, a fully worked example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <cusparse.h>
#include <cusolverSp.h>

//https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/all-the-ways-to-build-positive-definite-matrices.561438/
//https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101132-how-do-i-determine-if-a-matrix-is-positive-definite-using-matlab

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
//extern "C" int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }
__host__ __device__ int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
// --- Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { exit(code); }
    }
}

extern "C" void gpuErrchk(cudaError_t ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/**************************/
/* CUSOLVE ERROR CHECKING */
/**************************/
static const char *_cusolverGetErrorEnum(cusolverStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {
    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return "CUSOLVER_SUCCESS";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusolveSafeCall(cusolverStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if (CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSOLVE error in file '%s', line %d, error: %s \nterminating!\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
            _cusolverGetErrorEnum(err)); \
            assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusolveSafeCall(cusolverStatus_t err) { __cusolveSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/***************************/
/* CUSPARSE ERROR CHECKING */
/***************************/
static const char *_cusparseGetErrorEnum(cusparseStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSPARSE error in file '%s', line %Ndims\Nobjs %s\nerror %Ndims: %s\nterminating!\Nobjs", __FILE__, __LINE__, err, \
            _cusparseGetErrorEnum(err)); \
            cudaDeviceReset(); assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err) { __cusparseSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseHandle_t handle;    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    const int Nrows = 4;                        // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 4;                        // --- Number of columns
    const int N = Nrows;

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A_dense = (double*)malloc(Nrows*Ncols*sizeof(*h_A_dense));

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_A_dense[0] =  1.78;   h_A_dense[4] = 0.0;    h_A_dense[8]  =  0.1736; h_A_dense[12] = 0.0;
    h_A_dense[1] =  0.00;   h_A_dense[5] = 3.1;    h_A_dense[9]  =  0.0;    h_A_dense[13] = 0.0;
    h_A_dense[2] =  0.1736; h_A_dense[6] = 0.0;    h_A_dense[10] =  5.0;    h_A_dense[14] = 0.0;
    h_A_dense[3] =  0.00;   h_A_dense[7] = 0.0;    h_A_dense[11] =  0.0;    h_A_dense[15] = 2.349;

    //create device array and copy host to it
    double *d_A_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense, h_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix A
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;      cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSetMatType(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

    int nnz = 0;                                // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix
    const int lda = Nrows;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix
    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *d_nnzPerVector;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*d_nnzPerVector)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, &nnz));
    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *h_nnzPerVector = (int *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVector, d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix = %i\n\n", nnz);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVector[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // --- Device side dense matrix
    double *d_A;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, nnz * sizeof(*d_A)));
    int *d_A_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*d_A_RowIndices)));
    int *d_A_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*d_A_ColIndices)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices));

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A));
    int *h_A_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices));
    int *h_A_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, nnz*sizeof(*h_A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_RowIndices, d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_ColIndices, d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("A[%i] = %.0f ", i, h_A[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < (Nrows + 1); ++i) printf("h_A_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("h_A_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_ColIndices[i]);

    // --- Allocating and defining dense host and device data vectors
    double *h_y = (double *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(double));
    h_y[0] = 1.0;  h_y[1] = 1.0; h_y[2] = 1.0; h_y[3] = 1.0;

    double *d_y;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_y, Nrows * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_y, h_y, Nrows * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Allocating the host and device side result vector
    double *h_x = (double *)malloc(Ncols * sizeof(double));
    double *d_x;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_x, Ncols * sizeof(double)));

    // --- CUDA solver initialization
    cusolverSpHandle_t solver_handle;
    cusolverSpCreate(&solver_handle);

    // --- Using Cholesky factorization
    int singularity;
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverSpDcsrlsvcholHost(solver_handle, N, nnz, descrA, h_A, h_A_RowIndices, h_A_ColIndices, h_y, 0.000001, 0, h_x, &singularity));

    printf("Showing the results...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%f\n", h_x[i]);

}
```