# Solving general sparse linear systems in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I am currently working on `CUDA` and trying to solve `Ax = b` using `cuBLAS` and `cuSPARSE` library. I looked through the sample codes including `conjugateGradient` & `conjugateGradientPrecond` provided by NVIDIA. However, the conjugate gradient method only works for positive definite matrix and it is an iterative method. Now, I have some general sparse matrices and I think I should take advantage of `cuSPARSE` library. Does anyone know how can I solve `Ax = b` using `cuSPARSE` and `cuBLAS` libraries? I could not find useful APIs for me. Generally, the matrices are expected to be at least `1000x1000` and in some cases it would go up to `100000x100000`. Should I do this using a direct method?

Comment: How would you solve it in general?  What method would you use if you were solving it on the host?

Comment: I am thinking to use Cholesky or LU factorization (not the incomplete one in cuSparse library) and then get something like LUx = Pb so that I can solve for x.

Comment: If you want to use Cholesky, Tim Davis' CHOLMOD implementation in [suitesparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) is now GPU-enabled. The choice of whether to use a direct method or not will possibly depend on the matrix size, which you haven't stated.

Comment: Thanks for reminding! I have edited the question.

Comment: 1000x1000 is *tiny* for a sparse system.  You may want to investigate direct methods on the host, or even just use dense matrix algebra.  A 1000x1000 dense matrix of `double` only occupies 8MB.   "larger than 1000x1000" really gives no information at all.  It has no upper bound.  Give a bounded range for the matrix sizes you care about.

Comment: Thanks! The fact is that in some real cases the size of matrices would go up to 100000x100000 and I think it will not go over this number. But in most of cases, the size of the matrices should be around 50000x50000. 1000x1000 is a small case for testing purpose.

Answer (score 8):

One possibility to solve general sparse linear systems in CUDA is using `cuSOLVER`.

`cuSOLVER` has three useful routines:

1. `cusolverSpDcsrlsvlu`, which works for *square* linear systems (number of unknowns equal to the number of equations) and internally uses `sparse LU factorization with partial pivoting`;
2. `cusolverSpDcsrlsvqr`, which works for *square* linear systems (number of unknowns equal to the number of equations) and internally uses `sparse QR factorization`;
3. `cusolverSpDcsrlsqvqr`, which works for *rectangular* linear systems (number of unknowns different to the number of equations) and internally solves a `least square problem`.

For ALL the above routines, the supported matrix type is `CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL`. If `A` is symmetric/Hermitian and only lower/upper part is used or meaningful, then its missing upper/lower part must be extended.

**NOTES ON `cusolverSpDcsrlsvlu`**

Attention should be paid to two input parameters: `tol` and `reorder`. Concerning the former, if the system matrix `A` is singular, then some diagonal elements of the matrix `U` of the `LU` decomposition are zero. The algorithm decides for zero if `|U(j,j)|<tol`. Concerning the latter, cuSOLVER provides a reordering to reduce
zero fill-in which dramactically affects the performance of `LU factorization`. `reorder` toggles between reordering (`reorder=1`) or not reordering (`reorder=0`).

Attention should be paid also to an output parameter: `singularity`. It is `-1` if `A` is invertible, otherwise it provides the first index `j` such that `U(j,j)=0`.

**NOTES ON `cusolverSpDcsrlsvqr`**

Attention should be paid to the same input/output parameters are before. In particular, `tol` is used to decide for singularity, `reorder` has no effect and `singularity` is `-1` if `A` is invertible, otherwise it returns the first index `j` such that `R(j,j)=0`.

**NOTES ON `cusolverSpDcsrlsqvqr`**

Attention should be paid to the input parameter `tol`, which is used to decide the rank of `A`.

Attention should be also paid to the output parameters `rankA`, which represents the numerical rank of `A`, `p`, a permutation vector of length equal to the number of columns of `A` (please, see the documentation for further details) and `min_norm`, which is the norm of the residual `||Ax - b||`.

Currently, as of `CUDA 10.0`, the above three functions are for the *host channel* only, which means that they do not yet run on GPU. They must be called as:

1. `cusolverSpDcsrlsvluHost`;
2. `cusolverSpDcsrlsvqrHost`;
3. `cusolverSpDcsrlsqvqrHost`,

and the input argument should all reside on the host.

Below, please find a fully worked example using all the above three possibilities:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <cusparse.h>
#include <cusolverSp.h>

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
//extern "C" int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }
__host__ __device__ int iDivUp(int a, int b){ return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
// --- Credit to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api
void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort = true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { exit(code); }
    }
}

extern "C" void gpuErrchk(cudaError_t ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/**************************/
/* CUSOLVE ERROR CHECKING */
/**************************/
static const char *_cusolverGetErrorEnum(cusolverStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {
    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return "CUSOLVER_SUCCESS";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

    case CUSOLVER_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSOLVER_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusolveSafeCall(cusolverStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if (CUSOLVER_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSOLVE error in file '%s', line %d, error: %s \nterminating!\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, \
            _cusolverGetErrorEnum(err)); \
            assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusolveSafeCall(cusolverStatus_t err) { __cusolveSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/***************************/
/* CUSPARSE ERROR CHECKING */
/***************************/
static const char *_cusparseGetErrorEnum(cusparseStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

    case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT:
        return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if (CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSPARSE error in file '%s', line %Ndims\Nobjs %s\nerror %Ndims: %s\nterminating!\Nobjs", __FILE__, __LINE__, err, \
            _cusparseGetErrorEnum(err)); \
            cudaDeviceReset(); assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err) { __cusparseSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseHandle_t handle;    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    const int Nrows = 4;                        // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 4;                        // --- Number of columns
    const int N = Nrows;

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A_dense = (double*)malloc(Nrows*Ncols*sizeof(*h_A_dense));

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_A_dense[0] = 1.0f; h_A_dense[4] = 4.0f; h_A_dense[8] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[12] = 0.0f;
    h_A_dense[1] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[5] = 2.0f; h_A_dense[9] = 3.0f; h_A_dense[13] = 0.0f;
    h_A_dense[2] = 5.0f; h_A_dense[6] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[10] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[14] = 7.0f;
    h_A_dense[3] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[7] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[11] = 9.0f; h_A_dense[15] = 0.0f;

    //create device array and copy host to it
    double *d_A_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense, h_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix A
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;      cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSetMatType(descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    cusparseSetMatIndexBase(descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);

    int nnz = 0;                                // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix
    const int lda = Nrows;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix
    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *d_nnzPerVector;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*d_nnzPerVector)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, &nnz));
    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *h_nnzPerVector = (int *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVector, d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix = %i\n\n", nnz);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVector[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // --- Device side dense matrix
    double *d_A;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, nnz * sizeof(*d_A)));
    int *d_A_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*d_A_RowIndices)));
    int *d_A_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*d_A_ColIndices)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices));

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A));
    int *h_A_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices));
    int *h_A_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, nnz*sizeof(*h_A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_RowIndices, d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_ColIndices, d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("A[%i] = %.0f ", i, h_A[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < (Nrows + 1); ++i) printf("h_A_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("h_A_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_ColIndices[i]);

    // --- Allocating and defining dense host and device data vectors
    double *h_y = (double *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(double));
    h_y[0] = 100.0;  h_y[1] = 200.0; h_y[2] = 400.0; h_y[3] = 500.0;

    double *d_y;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_y, Nrows * sizeof(double)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_y, h_y, Nrows * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Allocating the host and device side result vector
    double *h_x = (double *)malloc(Ncols * sizeof(double));
    double *d_x;        gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_x, Ncols * sizeof(double)));

    // --- CUDA solver initialization
    cusolverSpHandle_t solver_handle;
    cusolverSpCreate(&solver_handle);

    // --- Using LU factorization
    int singularity;
    cusolveSafeCall(cusolverSpDcsrlsvluHost(solver_handle, N, nnz, descrA, h_A, h_A_RowIndices, h_A_ColIndices, h_y, 0.000001, 0, h_x, &singularity));
    // --- Using QR factorization
    //cusolveSafeCall(cusolverSpDcsrlsvqrHost(solver_handle, N, nnz, descrA, h_A, h_A_RowIndices, h_A_ColIndices, h_y, 0.000001, 0, h_x, &singularity));

    //int rankA;
    //int *p = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    //double min_norm;
    //cusolveSafeCall(cusolverSpDcsrlsqvqrHost(solver_handle, N, N, nnz, descrA, h_A, h_A_RowIndices, h_A_ColIndices, h_y, 0.000001, &rankA, h_x, p, &min_norm));

    printf("Showing the results...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) printf("%f\n", h_x[i]);

}
```